# how to shorten function query?

Tags: php, mysql, function

hello i have this function:

```
function mail_exists($email){
    global $db;
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM table1 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $check = $query->num_rows;
    $query2 = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM table2 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $check2 = $query->num_rows;
    return ($check > 0 || $check2 > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

first of all i would like to know how i can shorten it by using only one query and second thing is, why this does not work when using two queries? both tables have a different structure. in table1 the field email is no. 16 and on table2 it is field no.6.

thanks alot.

Comment: In what way does it not work when using two queries?

Comment: You don't need to return an explicitly named `true` or `false` value.  `return ($check > 0 || $check2 > 0);` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you made a logic error `*here` in the last lines: `$query->num_rows;` should be: `$query2->num_rows;` and then resulting into:

```
function mail_exists($email){
    global $db;
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM table1 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $check = $query->num_rows;
    $query2 = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM table2 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $check2 = $query2->num_rows; // *here
    return ($check > 0 || $check2 > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Second, you should be using two different queries if you are dealing with two completely different contexts. Don't join queries when you don't need to. If you are just counting rows you can easily do:

```
function mail_exists($email){
    global $db;
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $query2 = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $count1 = $query->fetch_row();
    $count2 = $query2->fetch_row();
    return ($count1[0] || $count2[0]);
}
```

The SQL `COUNT()` function is there to give you the most performant way to count rows.

Comment: hello and thank you very much for this explanation. i only have one question left: how does fetch_row work compared with num_rows. especially when i`m going to confirm while using return function. in case of return ($check > 0 || $check2 > 0) ? true : false; is this the same like return ($count1[0] || $count2[0]) ? true : false; or does  return ($count1[0] || $count2[0]); contains true/false? thanks alot.

Comment: @bonny, `fetch_row` fetch the result of the query into data. We use this in this context because the database in itself will count the rows for us and will return an `int` that need to be fetched and returned.

Comment: @bonny, Usually any `return (bool) ? true : false;` can be shortened into `return (bool)` because PHP parse any boolean expression inside `(bool)` returning `true` or `false` directly (without specifying `? true : false`).

Comment: @bonny, finally notice that anything that contains `and`, `or`, `||`, `Xor`, `&&` is usually considered to be a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use can `UNION ALL` to return an overall count:

```
SELECT Email
FROM (
   SELECT Email FROM table1 WHERE Email= '$email'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Email FROM table2 WHERE Email= '$email') t
```

Or you can use `SELECT COUNT(Email)` to return the count.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
SELECT t1.Email from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t2.Email=t1.Email WHERE t1.Email = '$email'
```

and then:

```
return $query->num_rows > 0;
```

I'm not a PHP expert, so your mileage may vary.